# From a table with 2 columns (key and value), how to return a json with values of the column?

Tags: json, sql-server, formatting

I have a table with 2 columns:

- key
- value

```sql
declare @myTable table ([Key] nvarchar(max), [value] nvarchar(max)) 
insert into @myTable ([key],value) values ('Timestamp', convert(varchar(max), getdate(), 120))
insert into @myTable ([key],value) values ('Number', '123456')
```

I want to have a JSON from this table with this format:

```json
[{"Timestamp":"2021-08-27 11:19:38"},{"Number":"123456"}]
```

I do a query like this:

```sql
SELECT [key],[value] FROM @myTable FOR JSON AUTO
```

But the result is:

```json
{"key":"Timestamp","value":"2021-08-27 11:19:38"},{"key":"Number","value":"123456"}
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pivot it first

```sql
SELECT
  [Timestamp],
  [Number]
-- if you want it as a number, not text, then use:
-- CAST([Number] AS int) [Number]
FROM @myTable t
PIVOT (
    MAX(value) FOR [key] IN ([Timestamp], [Number])
) pvt
FOR JSON PATH
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa1ccc8e6e58e92b1eba7755e6046686)

Comment: I have an empty result if I pivot

Comment: You have `key` and `value` in the wrong places in your `PIVOT`, Charlie.

Comment: @Larnu Whoops fixed thanks. To be honest, I'd love if you fixed those kind of things yourself, I'm not fussy like some others about people editing my answers. To be fair, should have done a fiddle in the first place

Comment: If I was fixing it, I'd be removing the whole `PIVOT` operator and using conditional aggregation, @Charlieface , and I think that would be a too big a change. ;)